# Program SegFaults right after a Constructor. C++

Tags: c++, class, constructor, segmentation-fault

I currently have a little problem on a program I'm coding, it segFaults just after a the constructor.

Here is some code :

```
void    GameEngine::createMap(std::vector<std::string> &parse)                                                                                                                                                       
{                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
  int   x;                                                                                                                                                                                                           
  int   y;                                                                                                                                                                                                           
  std::string strx;                                                                                                                                                                                                  
  std::string stry;                                                                                                                                                                                                  

  strx = parse.at(0);                                                                                                                                                                                                
  stry = parse.at(1);                                                                                                                                                                                                
  x = atoi(strx.c_str());                                                                                                                                                                                            
  y = atoi(stry.c_str());                                                                                                                                                                                            
  std::cout << "okokok" << std::endl;
  //_gMap is a Graphmap*;                                                                                                                                                                              
  this->_gMap = new GraphMap(x, y);                                                                                                                                                                                  
  std::cout << "okokokabc" << std::endl;                                                                                                                                                                             
}
```

createMap() is a function called when the server i'm connected to sends me "msz X Y\n", it's being called for sure. with valid X Y.

So here is a function that calls my class' (GraphMap) constructor. X and Y are to valid numbers

And here is the GraphMap Class.

The .hh

```
#ifndef GRAPHMAP_HH_
#define GRAPHMAP_HH_

class GameEngine;

class GraphMap
{
private:
  int   _height;
  int   _width;
  int   _squareSize;
public:
  GraphMap(int, int);
  ~GraphMap();
  void  draw(SDL_Renderer *);
};

#endif
```

And the .cpp:

```
#include "GameEngine.hh"
#include "GraphMap.hh"

GraphMap::GraphMap(int width, int height)
{
  std::cout << "testouilleee1" << std::endl;
  _width = width;
  std::cout << "testouilleee2" << std::endl;
  _height = height;
  std::cout << "testouilleee3" << std::endl;
  _squareSize = 1000 / width;
  std::cout << "testouilleee4" << std::endl;
}

GraphMap::~GraphMap() {}

void    GraphMap::draw(SDL_Renderer *renderer)
{
  int   i;
  int   j;
  for(i = 1 ; i <= _width ; i++)
    {
      for (j = 1 ; j <= _height ; j++)
        {
          SDL_Rect rect;
          rect.x = ((i - 1) * _squareSize);
          rect.y = ((j - 1) * _squareSize);
          rect.w = _squareSize - 1;
          rect.h = _squareSize - 1;
          SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 0, 255, 0, 255);
          SDL_RenderFillRect(renderer, &rect);
        }
      j = 1;
    }
}
```

The thing that i can't understand is that the output is :

```
$ ./run.sh 
okokok
testouilleee1
testouilleee2
testouilleee3
testouilleee4
./run.sh: line 12: 10414 Segmentation fault      (core dumped) ./zappy_graph 127.0.0.1 4242
```

That means it goes to the last line of the constructor but then segFaults and do not prints the "okokokabc" which I can not understand

Here are some debug info from GDB :

```
0x0000000000404556 in GameEngine::createMap (this=0x0, parse=...) at GameEngine.cpp:90
90    this->_gMap = new GraphMap(x, y);
(gdb) bt
#0  0x0000000000404556 in GameEngine::createMap (this=0x0, parse=...) at GameEngine.cpp:90
#1  0x000000000040561b in Command::msz (this=0x712360, cmd=..., game=0x0) at Command.cpp:32
#2  0x000000000040647c in Command::Parse (this=0x712360, command=..., game=0x0) at Command.cpp:138
#3  0x000000000040949b in Socket::selectSocket (this=0x7120a0) at Socket.cpp:67
#4  0x000000000040441e in GameEngine::update (this=0x712010) at GameEngine.cpp:58
#5  0x00000000004046f0 in GameEngine::run (this=0x712010) at GameEngine.cpp:110
#6  0x000000000040968e in main (ac=1, av=0x7fffffffdd78) at main.cpp:22

(gdb) print x
$1 = 20
(gdb) print y
$2 = 20
```

If you need more info/code just tell me i'll post it as soon as I can.

Comment: Run a debug build in a debugger instead, it will stop at the location of the crash, letting you examine both variables and the call stack. If the debugger stops in library code, then walk up the call stack until you're at your code.

Comment: Also think about what would happen if `width` is zero, which could happen if the string provided to `atoi` doesn't start with a digit (or if it's the string `"0"` of course). You should really use [`std::stoi`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol) (or [`strtol`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strtol)) instead as then you can check for errors.

Comment: stoi doesn't change anything width and height are both equal 20 (the value I use as a test)

Comment: I didn't expect anything to change, it's just easier to catch errors with `std::stoi` and `strtol`.

Comment: OK, I edit the question with some debug from GDB

Comment: Then the next question, is the object valid? I.e. is `this` a valid pointer to a non-constant object of class `GameEngine`?

Comment: So I tried this next thing :
`If (this)
{
    std::cout << "this is ok" << std::endl;
}`
It  doesn't display anything

Comment: Basically the game I was giving to Command::Parse() wasn't initiated because the class that called parse had an attribute GamEngine _game that wasn't initialized ... very bad from me here ! Thanks a lot @JoachimPileborg for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GDB shown that the `GameEngine` address is `0x0`:

> ```
> GameEngine::createMap (this=0x0...
> ```

So the problem is that for some reason the GameEngine pointer is wrong (was not initialized or corrupted).

Note that this pointer seems to come from at least

> ```
> Command::Parse (this=0x712360, command=..., game=0x0)
> ```

(I suppose the last parameter is the GameEngine itself?)

Note also that some lines below there is a correct `GameEngine` object:

> ```
> GameEngine::update (this=0x712010) at GameEngine.cpp:58
> ```

If you have only one `GameEngine` in your program (which I assume is the case), then this means that `GameEngine` address is somehow lost between `GameEngine::update()` and `Command::Parse()`.

Comment: Basically the game I was giving to Command::Parse() wasn't initiated because the class that called parse had an attribute GameEngine _game that wasn't initialized ... That was a very dumb mistake from me here . thanks a lot !